# Renders perfect on Chrome and Firefox but is awful on IE

Tags: html, w3.css

I have a project at the moment to create an enquiry form that our company can use to direct sales enquiries to the sales team.

I am going to implement a single web page for this to capture details and send them to our internal sales system.

For this I want to use IE for the following reasons:
1. not everyone has Chrome or Firefox etc.
2. I want to also use a bit of vbs to pass logged on username etc into the webform.
3. I can create a toolbar-less, scrollbar-less window that keeps things neat.

I have started putting the page together using w3.css. It is the first time I've used w3.css.

Is anyone able to tell me why it works with other browsers but not IE?
I have the  I'm referencing all the correct css yet I am getting some odd results.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Certsure Sales Enquiry Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <style>
    body {
      padding: 30px;
      background-color: #262626;
      }
    
    .button {
      border-radius: 12px;
      background-color: #c50736;
      color: white;
      padding: 10px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 15px;
      border:none;
      border-radius: 4px;
      cursor: pointer; 
      }
  
    .submit-container {
      padding:20px;
      }
    </style>

    <body>
    <div class="w3-container w3-teal">
    <h1>Certsure Sales Enquiry Form</h1>
    <p>Please enter information below</p>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-container w3-light-gray w3-center">
    <div class="w3-cell-row">
      <div class="w3-container w3-cell w3-third">Schemes</div>
      <div class="w3-container w3-cell w3-third">Training</div>
      <div class="w3-container w3-cell w3-third">Direct</div>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-cell-row">
      <div class="w3-container w3-cell w3-quarter">Name<br/><input type="text" name="Name" class="w3-input w3-border w3-round"></div>
      <div class="w3-container w3-cell w3-quarter">Phone<br/><input type="text" name="Phone" class="w3-input w3-border w3-round"></div>
      <div class="w3-container w3-cell w3-quarter">Email<br/><input type="text" name="Email" class="w3-input w3-border w3-round"></div>
      <div class="w3-container w3-cell w3-quarter">Company Name<br/><input type="text" name="Company Name" class="w3-input w3-border w3-round"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="submit-container">
    <button class="button w3-hover-black" name="Send Enquiry" id="Send Enquiry" onclick="OnClickButtonSendEnquiry">Send enquiry</button>
    </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Odd results? What are they? How should it look? How does it look? What’s the issue?

Comment: Can't reproduce. I get identical results for IE11, latest Chrome and latest Firefox.

Comment: Which version of IE are you testing on @Joe Hayes?

Comment: Unrelated to that, "Send Enquiry" as an attribute id is invalid: An ID must not contain whitespace.

Comment: Here are the differences I am getting     Chrome - https://imageshack.com/a/img922/8567/x6wM5O.png     IE11 - https://imageshack.com/a/img923/4632/d1wo1O.jpg     The content in IE11 has line breaks after everything even though I haven't specified any.

Comment: It's because in IE your window is smaller. Try resizing in any browser und you get this result.

Comment: Even when I maximize the window it remains the same

Comment: I solved this by removing some <!--> code from before the DOCTYPE. Still not totally sure what issue was but its working. Thanks for everyones input though